# Operating on a return from a Maybe that contains "Just"

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I have a function that has a return type of `Maybe ([(Int,Int)],(Int,Int))`

I would like to call this from another function and perform an operation on the data.

However, the return value is contained within `Just`. The second method takes `([(Int,Int)],(Int,Int))` and therefore will not accept `Just ([(Int,Int)],(Int,Int))`.

Is there a way I can trim the `Just` before applying the second method?

I don't fully understand the use of `Just` within `Maybe` - however, I have been told that the return type for the first Method must be `Maybe`.

Comment: Maybe is used if your unsure of the type of the return value. For instance is your method could return an error string.

Comment: @Jonathan Fischoff: Maybe is *not* used if you're unsure of the type. There is no way a method returnng `Maybe ([(Int,Int)],(Int,Int))` could return an error string. Maybe is used when you don't know if you'll have a value to return or not, so you can either return Just the value or Nothing.

Comment: @Jonathan Fischoff: Partly correct. You use Maybe when there may be no result (Nothing), for example `getPosition :: List a -> Maybe Integer`. You use `Either` to return either (no pun intended) a valid return value (Right) or an error (Left). Edit: @Chuck was faster.

Comment: @Chunk I think you took me too literally. I was referring to how Maybe's are used many Haskell libraries.

Answer (score 51):

There are several solutions to your problem, all based around pattern matching. I'm assuming you have two algorithms (since you didn't name them, I will):

```
algorithm1 :: a -> Maybe b
algorithm2 :: b -> c
input :: a
```

1) [Pattern matching](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching) is typically done from either a case statement (below) or a function.

```
let val = algorithm1 input
in case val of
    Nothing -> defaultValue
    Just x  -> algorithm2 x
```

All other presented solutions use pattern matching, I'm just presenting standard functions that perform the pattern matching for you.

2) The prelude (and Data.Maybe) have some built-in functions to deal with `Maybe`s.  The  [maybe](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Prelude.html#v:maybe) function is a great one, I suggest you use it.  It's defined in standard libraries as:

```
maybe :: c -> (b -> c) -> Maybe b -> c
maybe n _ Nothing  = n
maybe _ f (Just x) = f x
```

Your code would look like:

```
maybe defaultValue algorithm2 (algorithm1 input)
```

3) Since Maybe is a [functor](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Control-Monad.html#t%3AFunctor) you could use [fmap](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Prelude.html#v:fmap).  This makes more sense if you don't have a default value.  The definition:

```
instance  Functor Maybe  where
    fmap _ Nothing       = Nothing
    fmap f (Just a)      = Just (f a)
```

So your code would look like:

```
fmap algorithm2 (algorithm1 input)
```

This output will be a `Maybe` value (`Nothing` if the result of algorithm1 is `Nothing`).

4) Finally, and strongly discouraged, is `fromJust`.  Only use it if you are positive the first algorithm will return `Just x` (and not `Nothing`).  Be careful!  If you call `fromJust val` when `val = Nothing` then you get an exception, which is not appreciated in Haskell.  Its definition:

```
fromJust          :: Maybe b -> b
fromJust Nothing  = error "Maybe.fromJust: Nothing" -- yuck
fromJust (Just x) = x
```

Leaving your code to look like:

```
algorithm2 (fromJust (algorithm1 input))
```

Comment: I'd put it the other way round: pattern matching is the canonical way of dealing with a `Maybe` result, the others are just abbreviations for common ways to do that. (Since the OP probably doesn't know them, I'd state their definitions, too.)

Comment: Good point.  In retrospect I think I started with `fromJust` merely because that was the answer already given and informally accepted by the asker.

Comment: Despite `yuck`, I find fromJust the easiest way to understand this. Thanks for your answer in any case.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [`fromJust`](http://www.zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputmaybe/fromJust_f.html). But only if you're **certain** your `Maybe` function is not going to return a `Nothing`!

Comment: Thank you, that'll do it.

It always returns a value when called from this method because I'm just recycling a method written for something else.

Comment: fromJust is considered bad form in Haskell -- as are any partial functions like `head`.  I would recommend either of the alternatives in TomMD's answer.