# Using Maybe type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, option-type

I'm trying to utilize the Maybe type in Haskell.  I have a lookup for key, value tuples that returns a Maybe.  How do I access the data that was wrapped by Maybe?  For example I want to add the integer contained by Maybe with another integer.

Comment: This is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375483/operating-on-a-return-from-a-maybe-that-contains-just/3375712#3375712

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Alternatively you can pattern match:

```
case maybeValue of
  Just value -> ...
  Nothing    -> ...
```

Comment: This was more like what I was trying to do than the answer I had found.  Thanks

Comment: What should I say in the type declaration?

Answer (score 25):

You could use `Data.Maybe.fromMaybe`, which takes a `Maybe a` and a value to use if it is `Nothing`. You could use the unsafe `Data.Maybe.fromJust`, which will just crash if the value is `Nothing`. You likely want to keep things in `Maybe`. If you wanted to add an integer in a `Maybe`, you could do something like

```
f x = (+x) <$> Just 4
```

which is the same as

```
f x = fmap (+x) (Just 4)
```

`f 3` will then be `Just 7`.  (You can continue to chain additional computations in this manner.)

Comment: `f 3` will be `Just 7`, not `7`.

Answer (score 9):

Just as a side note: Since `Maybe` is a `Monad`, you can build computations using `do`-notation ...

```
sumOfThree :: Maybe Int
sumOfThree = do
  a <- someMaybeNumber
  b <- someMaybeNumber
  c <- someMaybeNumber
  let k = 42 -- Just for fun
  return (a + b + c + k)
```

Answer (score 8):

Examples for "maybe":

```
> maybe 0 (+ 42) Nothing
0
> maybe 0 (+ 42) (Just 12)
54
```

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, I should have googled better.

using the fromMaybe function is exactly what I need.  fromMaybe will return the value in Maybe if it is not nothing, otherwise it will return a default value supplied to fromMaybe.

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Maybe.html

Comment: Yeah but make sure that is the behaviour that you want, because if you are going to, for example, use a Maybe Int and then every time that it is Nothing you return zero then you should have just used a plain old Int right from the start. Maybe is supposed to help encode the absence of a result or value and not really supposed to be worked around. Personally I try to steer as clear of the fromMaybe function.

Answer (score 4):

Many people are against the use of `fromJust`, however it can be convenient if you are aware of what will happen when the lookup fails (error!!)

Firstly you will need this:

```
import Data.Maybe
```

And then your lookup from a list of tuples will look like this

```
Data.Maybe.fromJust $ lookup key listOfTuples
```

For example, successful lookup:

```
Data.Maybe.fromJust $ lookup "a" [("a",1),("b",2),("c",3)]
1
```

And horrible failure looks like this:

```
Data.Maybe.fromJust $ lookup "z" [("a",1),("b",2),("c",3)]
*** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
```