# How to return value without Maybe after use lookup to get the value from the table?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to return a string and combine it with another.
A table has been made with the following code.

```
type Table = [(Char, String)]
```

and the Table look like this.

```
t = [(A, "Apple"),(B, "Boy"),(C, "Car"),(D, "Day")...]
```

I would like to combine the string and return it. For example

```
(lookup 'A' t) ++ (lookup 'B' t) = "AppleBoy"
```

But its not be able to do that because a maybe value has been returned after lookup function.
Please help me to understand how to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643172/using-maybe-type-in-haskell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lift the `++` function to the `Applicative` level with `liftA2`:

```hs
import Control.Applicative
liftA2 (++) (lookup 'A' t) (lookup 'B' t)
-- Just "AppleBoy"
```

Alternatively, this can be written as:

```hs
(++) <$> (lookup 'A' t) <*> (lookup 'B' t)
```

[See this excellent chapter from Learn you a Haskell for more information](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids).