# How to declare function (type misunderstanding Maybe)

Tags: haskell

I need a function which works like:

```
some :: (Int, Maybe Int) -> Int
some a b
     | b == Nothing = 0
     | otherwise = a + b
```

Use cases:

```
some (2,Just 1)
some (3,Nothing)
map some [(2, Just 1), (3,Nothing)]
```

But my code raise the error:

```
The equation(s) for `some' have two arguments,
but its type `(Int, Maybe Int) -> Int' has only one
```

I don't understand it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `some = uncurry $ maybe 0 . (+)`

Comment: You might be interested in the more generic question of how to work with a `Maybe a` type, [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375483/operating-on-a-return-from-a-maybe-that-contains-just/3375712#3375712).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you write

```
foo x y = ...
```

That is notation for a *curried* function, with a type like:

```
foo :: a -> b -> c
```

You have declared your function to expect a tuple, so you must write it:

```
some :: (Int, Maybe Int) -> Int
some (x, y) = ...
```

But Haskell convention is usually to take arguments in the former curried form.  Seeing funcitons take tuples as arguments is very rare.

For the other part of your question, you probably want to express it with pattern matching.  You could say:

```
foo :: Maybe Int -> Int
foo Nothing = 0
foo (Just x) = x + 1
```

Generalizing that to the OP's question is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks. Pattern matching is that I need.

Comment: Rather than pattern matching, I would probably write it `some a b = fromMaybe 0 (fmap (+ a) b)`, and point-free it to `some a = fromMaybe 0 . fmap (+ a)`.

Comment: @John, do you think it is helpful to suggest the use of Functors and point-free style to someone who does not grasp currying and pattern matching yet?

Answer (score 7):

Your error doesn't come from a misunderstanding of `Maybe`: The type signature of `some` indicates that it takes a pair `(Int, Maybe Int)`, while in your definition you provide it two arguments. The definition should thus begin with `some (a,b)` to match the type signature.

One way to fix the problem (which is also a bit more idiomatic and uses pattern matching) is:

```
some :: (Int, Maybe Int) -> Int
some (a, Nothing) = a
some (a, Just b) = a + b
```

It's also worth noting that unless you have a really good reason for using a tuple as input, you should probably not do so. If your signature were instead `some :: Int -> Maybe Int -> Int`, you'd have a function of two arguments, which can be [curried](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Then you'd write something like

```
some :: Int -> Maybe Int -> Int
some a Nothing = a
some a (Just b) = a + b
```

Also, you might want to add the following immediate generalization: All `Num` types are additive, so you might aswell do

```
some :: (Num n) => n -> Maybe n -> n
some a Nothing = a
some a (Just b) = a + b
```

(I've violated the common practice of using a, b, c... for type variables so as not to confuse the OP since he binds `a` and `b` to the arguments of `some`).