# Extract a from [a]

Tags: list, haskell, extract

how can I easily take the following

```
[4]
```

and return the following:

```
4
```

I know that [4]!!0 works but doesn't seem to be a good strategy...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just pattern match it:

```
getSingleton [a] = a
```

Answer (score 6):

`head` is the normal answer, which you see three of (one with a custom name) - this is functionally the same as what you already know (`x !! 0` ~ `head x`).  I strongly suggest against partial functions unless you can prove (with local knowledge) that you'll never pass an empty list and result in a run-time exception.

If your function doesn't guarantee a non-empty list then use `listToMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a`:

```
> listToMaybe [4]
Just 4
> listToMaybe [5,39,-2,6,1]
Just 5
> listToMaybe []
Nothing            -- A 'Nothing' constructor instead of an exception
```

Once you have the `Maybe a` you can pattern match on that, keep it as Maybe and use `fmap` or a Maybe monad, or [some other method to perform further operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375483/operating-on-a-return-from-a-maybe-that-contains-just/3375712#3375712).

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively to gatoatigrado's solution you can also use the `head` function, which extracts the first element of a list, but will also work on lists with more than one element and additionally is a standard function in the Prelude. You just have to be careful not to apply it to empty lists or you will get a runtime exception.

```
Prelude> head [4]
4
Prelude> head []
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't do exactly the same as gatoatigrado's solution. Specifically `head` will return the first element of a list of multiple elements while `getSingleton` would cause an error if a list of more than element is given. Which is preferable depends on the use case of course.

Comment: oh, yes, you're right, thanks for pointing that out, i overlooked that. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this first item in a list you can just do

```
head [4]
```

Answer (score 0):

`[]` is a monad. So you use the monad "extract" operation, `<-`

```
double x = 2*x

doubleAll xs = do x <- xs
                  return (double x)
```

Of course, the result of the monadic computation is returned in the monad. ;)