# Haskell simple GUI program: "can't match X against Maybe X"

Tags: user-interface, haskell

hello I am very beginer of haskell

I am making GUI program that

1. open file selection dialog
2. take word
3. search the word in selected txt file
4. print number of found to label

but I stuck with error which I can't solve it

I paste error and code here

could somebody please help me?

thank you

the full code is here

```
--GUI routine
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Text.Regex.Posix ((=~))
import Control.Monad (when)
--core routine
matchWord :: String -> String -> Int
matchWord file word = length . filter (== word) . concat $ file =~ "[^- \".,\n]+"
--main start
main :: IO ()
main =
      do initGUI
         win <- windowNew
         windowSetTitle win "WORD SEARCHER"
         win `onDestroy` mainQuit

         fch <- fileChooserWidgetNew FileChooserActionOpen
         containerAdd win fch 

         targetFile <- fileChooserGetFilename fch --wrong?

         ent <- entryNew
         btn <- buttonNew
         st <- labelNew $ Just "Found : 0      "

         col <- vBoxNew False 5
         containerAdd col ent
         containerAdd col btn
         containerAdd col st    

         buttonSetLabel btn "Click to search"

         btn `onClicked` do targetWord <- entryGetText ent
                            fileData <- readFile targetFile
                            found <- matchWord fileData targetWord
                            labelSetText st found
         containerAdd win col
         widgetShowAll win
         mainGUI
```

the error is here

```
gui-word-search.hs:33:49:
    Couldn't match expected type `FilePath'
       against inferred type `Maybe FilePath'
    In the first argument of `readFile', namely `targetFile'
    In a 'do' expression: fileData <- readFile targetFile
```

Comment: If you're unsure how to handle a `Maybe` (`targetFile` is of type `Maybe FilePath`) to get a `FilePath` out then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375483/operating-on-a-return-from-a-maybe-that-contains-just/3375712#3375712) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fileChooserGetFilename` can't always return a filename (the user might click on "cancel" for example). For that reason its return type is `Maybe FilePath`, not `FilePath`. So if a file was chosen, it returns a `Just` containing the `FilePath`. If no file was chosen it returns `Nothing`.

However `readFile` takes a `FilePath` as an argument, not a `Maybe FilePath` (calling `readFile` with `Nothing` makes no sense).

So what you need to do is you need to pattern match on `targetFile`. If it is `Nothing`, you need to handle that somehow (you could print an error message, or just keep asking the user for a file until he picks one), and if it's a `Just`, you take the `FilePath` it contains and feed that to `readFile`.