# Search through a haskell list

Tags: haskell, return

So I have this calculator I'm building that accepts user variable inputs like "let a = 2" These variable are stored in a List of Tuples (Variable, value) I need help with getting the data from this list. My code so far

```
primary :: Parser Float
primary = do symbol "("
         e <- expression
         symbol ")"
         return e
       +++ do v <- identifier                 
              let a = (find (==(head v)) vlist)
              return a
```

I get an error because find returns a Maybe and I need it to return a Float or give the user an error message. How do I do this?

Comment: You're looking for a previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375483/operating-on-a-return-from-a-maybe-that-contains-just

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where `vlist` comes from.  It should probably be part of the parser's user state.  For now, let's assume it's a top-level definition:

```
vlist :: [(String, Float)]
vlist = undefined -- fill in the blanks...
```

I assume you're using `Parsec`.  You can simplify your parser to:

```
primary :: Parser Float
primary = choice [ between (symbol "(") (symbol ")") expression
                 , do { ident <- identifier
                      ; case lookup ident vlist of
                          Nothing -> fail $ "No such identifier: " ++ ident
                          Just v -> return v
                      }
                 ]
```

You have several options for how to deal with the error.  Here, I have used the parser monad's `fail` function.  This will cause the parser to return a `Left parserError`.  Alternatively, you could substitute `error` for `fail`, which will result in an error that can only be handled in the `IO` monad.

**Note**:  To add the `vlist` as parser state, you need to define a new parser type with that state:

```
data MyParserState = MyParserState { vlist :: [(String, Float)] }
type MyParser = CharParser MyParserState

-- these parsers now need to return MyParser type!
symbol :: String -> MyParser String
identifier :: MyParser String
expression :: MyParser Float

primary :: MyParser Float
primary = choice [ between (symbol "(") (symbol ")") expression
                 , do { st <- getState
                      ; ident <- identifier
                      ; case lookup ident $ vlist st of
                          Nothing -> fail $ "No such identifier: " ++ ident
                          Just v -> return v
                      }
                 ]
```

Comment: Ok I think I follow what you are saying, and yes this is pretty much the definition for vlist. What is choice? I'm not sure what that is?

Comment: `choice ps` tries to apply the parsers in the list `ps` in order, until one of them succeeds.  I just realized that you were using `+++`, which is used by `ReadP` parsers, and not `Parsec` parsers.  I find that `choice` is nicer than a string of parsers joined together with `<|>` since you don't need to put parens around the elements when they contain a lower precedence operator.

Comment: You should make `MyParserState` a `newtype` or even, if you are me, just use `[(String, Float)]`

Comment: @monadic, good point.  A record with only one field is a bit silly, I was simply anticipating the eventual need for more state.  That being said, you are absolutely correct that a record with only one field can be a `newtype` (I had to go check that!), but a record with more than one field must be a `data`.  Oh, and in real life, I wouldn't name the field `vlist`, but that's a whole other story...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps run it through a `case x of` block like so:

```
case find x of (Just y) -> --your code here
               Nothing  -> error "Wrong"
```