# How to return last element in the list using function in haskell?

Tags: haskell

My professor gave me an example to get last element in the list using "`laste`" function:
he stated that: definition in the form of “`laste xs = …`” is not acceptable, whereas definition in the form of “`laste  = …`” is acceptable.

I have tried something like this: Please correct me if my solution is wrong according to problem statement.

```
laste :: [a] -> Maybe a 
laste [] = Nothing 
laste (x:[]) = Just x 
laste (x:xs) = laste xs
```

But this gives me answer for example:

```
ghci>laste[1,2,3,4]
Just 4
```

I want to get rid of this "`Just`".

Is there any solution to remove `Just`?

Comment: See the fromJust function: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromJust . Alternatively, just eliminate the constructor, `let (Just x) = laste[1,2,3,4] in x`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operating on a return from a Maybe that contains "Just"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375483/operating-on-a-return-from-a-maybe-that-contains-just)

Comment: It looks like your homework is to express this in "point free" format. Your definition works fine, but now instead of expressing it like this, you need to express it as a combination of other functions, some of which you may have to define.

Comment: *I want to get rid of this "Just"* — what do you want `laste []` to return?

Comment: Is a definition of the form `laste = last` acceptable?

Comment: In definition, you must not explicitly give an argument to “laste”. For instance, definition in the form of “laste xs = …” is not acceptable, whereas definition in the form of “laste  = …” is OK. Thats what my preofessor said@ n.m

Comment: @PaulJohnson Or he could just use a lambda and a case statement.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to change the signature of the function to return a simple element.

The thing is that you would need to return an error in case of empty list.

```
laste :: [a] -> a
laste []     = error "Can't handle empty lists." -- or some other error message
laste [x]    = x
laste (x:xs) = laste xs
```

Answer (score 4):

While Charmini2's answer is functionally correct, it doesn't solve the problem of retrieving the last element in pointfree form. Consider

```
laste :: [a] -> a
laste = foldr1 (\_ a -> a)
```

It works according to specs as foldr1 expects a non-empty list. Intuition for why it returns the last element in the list can be gotten from the observation that foldr1 replaces every (:) in the structure of the list with the lambda in the above equation, which basically selects the rightmost of two elements. Repeat, and you get the last.

Answer (score 2):

I think your professor meant was that you need to re-implement the Prelude function last
in a [point-free style](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree).

```
non point-free example:
filterEven xs = filter even xs

point-free     exapmle:
filterEven    = filter even

point-free examples of last:
lastv1 = (head . reverse)
lastv2 = foldl1 (\acc x -> x)
lastv3 = foldr1 (\x acc -> acc)
lastv4 = \(x:xs) -> if null xs then x else lastv4 xs
lastv5 = \e -> case e of
    [x] -> x
    (_:xs) -> lastv5 xs
    otherwise -> error "empty list"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a possible working solution:

```
last' :: [a]    -> a
last'    []     =  error "empty"
last'    (x:[]) =  x
last'    (x:xs) =  last' xs
```