# How can I extract an IO () from Maybe and execute this?

Tags: haskell, monads

I have this code:

```
trick = Just (putStrLn "Hello?")
```

And I want to unwrap this `IO ()` out the Maybe context and call it.

```
main = do foo <- trick
          foo
```

However, this throws an error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘Maybe’
Expected type: Maybe ()
  Actual type: IO ()
```

How could I resolve this?

Comment: There's a nice function: `maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `Data.Foldable.sequence_`:

```
>>> Data.Foldable.sequence_ (Just (putStrLn "Hello?"))
Hello?
>>>
```

If your `Maybe` is `Nothing`, it will not do anything:

```
>>> Data.Foldable.sequence_ Nothing
>>>
```

This works because the type of `Data.Foldable.sequence_` is:

```
Data.Foldable.sequence_
    :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m ()
```

... and if you specialize `t` to `Maybe` and `m` to `IO`, you get:

```
Data.Foldable.sequence_ :: Maybe (IO a) -> IO ()
```

In the specific context of `Maybe`, it's equivalent to:

```
sequence_ (Just io) = do
    _ <- io
    return ()
sequence   Nothing  = return ()
```

Comment: @Thelost Where is Gabriel using `case` ?

Comment: @Thelost Sure, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375483/operating-on-a-return-from-a-maybe-that-contains-just/3375712#3375712   In brief: `maybe (return ()) id trick`

Comment: or `fromMaybe (return ()) trick`, which is also equivalent to `sequence_ trick`.

Comment: @Thelost You would use a function like `maybe` or `fromMaybe`, like the others suggested.  Those function are themselves implemented in terms of pattern matching (equivalent to `case`)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution to start out with is probably to realize that you can decide what to do based on the value of the `Maybe (IO ())` via pattern matching.

```
maybeDoIO :: Maybe (IO ()) -> IO ()
maybeDoIO (Just io) = io
maybeDoIO Nothing   = return ()
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the `Nothing` into account, basically:

```
main = maybe (putStrLn "Nothing") id foo
```

Comment: @Thelost `maybe` requires a default value to provide in case the extraction of `Maybe` fails.

Comment: @Thelost ah you're right I got the argument order wrong. Fixed.

Comment: If the op really wants the program to do nothing if the value is Nothing, then `putStrLn "Nothing"` can just be changed to `return ()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your `main` function is that you are mixing two different monads in the same `do` block.

The `foo <- trick` action is "relative" to the `Maybe` monad but the `foo` action afterwards is an `IO` action. The type for `>>=` is:

```
Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

But in your case you'd need something with type:

```
Maybe a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
```

with two different monads.

If you want to execute the `IO` action then the type of `main` **must** be of the kind `IO a` so the `do` notation must refer to `IO` and not `Maybe`. Which means that you *cannot* use `<-` to extract the action but you have to use something else. For example `Data.Maybe.fromMaybe`:

```
import Data.Maybe

main = do fromMaybe (return ()) trick
```

Comment: Is there some kind of `m1 a -> (a -> m2 b) -> m2 b` in the standard?

Comment: @Thelost `m2` would need to be able to run `m1`. Try `m1 ~ IO` and `m2 ~ Id`