# Extract a real or default value from a Monad with fmap or <$> or the likes -- how?

Tags: haskell

Suppose, I have this function which accepts a Maybe arg:

```
func1 :: Maybe Int -> Int
func1 mbArg = 
  let var1 = case myArg of
               Just x -> x
               Nothing -> -1
  -- ....
```

I wonder, is there any other way to do the same thing but using something like `mapM`, `mapM_` or `fmap` or `<$>` or anything similar? That is, check if it's Just or Nothing and extract the real value or return the default value respectively.

My question is about Maybe as a Monad.

Comment: You can use `fromMaybe` or `maybe` for this purpose.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375483/operating-on-a-return-from-a-maybe-that-contains-just

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, from a Monad.

Comment: That doesn't change my understanding of the question.  You have a `value :: Maybe a` and a function of type `a -> Maybe b` and wish to use them in a monadic style?  If that's true then `value >>= function`.  That is, the bind operator is what you want, `do v <- value; function v`

Comment: for general extracting values from monads, you may take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567743/how-to-extract-value-from-monadic-action