# Using Network.URL library in Haskell

Tags: haskell, option-type

After reading the Yesod book, I'm sold on the idea of using typesafe URLs rather than raw string-likes.  I'm just trying some simple get requests, rather than using the full yesod library, but seemed like it would be easy enough to either define a custom URL data type deriving show, or to use some other existing minimal URL library.

I found this on Hoogle:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/url-2.1.3/docs/Network-URL.html

Seems like it will do the kind of validation I want, so that a mistake like:

```
myothervar = "kittens"   -- oh no, I defined this for something else
parseRequest myothervar  -- and called it from parseRequest!
```

will be caught by the compiler, while

```
myurl = "http://example.com"
parseRequest myurl
```

...will succeed, great.

```
ghci    λ> import Network.URL
ghci    λ> myurl = importURL "http://example.com"
```

Documentation suggests to me I need to use importURL

```
ghci    λ> :t myurl
myurl :: Maybe URL
```

Great, I know how to de-`Maybe`, I use `Just`.

```
ghci    λ> exportURL $ Just myurl

<interactive>:47:13: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘URL’
                  with actual type ‘Maybe (Maybe URL)’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘Just myurl’
      In the expression: exportURL $ Just myurl
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = exportURL $ Just myurl

ghci    λ> Just (Just (URL {url_type = Absolute (Host {protocol = HTTP False, host = "example.com", port = Nothing}), url_path = "", url_params = []}))
```

OK, what?  That didn't remove my Just, it just added another Just.  How can I retrieve the String that `parseRequest` will take as an argument?

And it looks like I definitely need to de-Maybe it by exporting back to String somehow:

```
ghci    λ> import Network.HTTP.Conduit
ghci    λ> parseRequest $ myurl

<interactive>:84:16: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Maybe URL’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: Maybe URL
```

Comment: Err, `Just` does not “de-maybe”, it is one of the two constructor for the `Maybe` type. In fact, you *cannot* de-maybe in general, because what if the value is `Nothing`? There would be no `URL` “inside” the value to get out. If you’re sure the value will really be a `Just`, though, you can use `fromJust`, but use that with extreme caution! It will just crash your program at runtime if the value is not a `Just` throwing away the whole type safety point of using `Maybe`.

Comment: On the "de-maybe" issue, you might be mixing up the use of `Just` as a function to build a `Maybe`-value (e.g. in the type mismatch that surprised you) with its use for pattern matching (e.g. on the left side of an equals sign). For suggestions on how to handle the `Maybe`-value, [*Operating on a return from a Maybe that contains “Just”*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3375483/2751851) is a good start.

Comment: Note: nowadays using network-uri's Network.URI module seems a better choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things worth discussing here:

> OK, what? That didn't remove my Just, it just added another Just. How can I retrieve the String that parseRequest will take as an argument?

Remember something that has type `Maybe URL` is either a `Nothing` or a `Just url` where `url :: URL`. You can't just "extract" the some part of the `URL` because the whole point of `Maybe` is that *you might not have a `URL` at all*!

> How can I retrieve the String that parseRequest will take as an argument?

This is unnecessary - `parseRequest` is doing the same thing as `importURL` - it is just checking that the URL is properly formed. The only difference is that it signals an error by throwing an error using `throwM` from `MonadThrow`. Furthermore, if you want to use `http-conduit`, you will need to use `parseRequest` anyways to get a `Request`, so there really is no point to having `importURL` there at all.

If you are worried about a badly formed `URL`, you can make sure to wrap the code in a [`catch`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.8.3/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#v:catch).

```
import Network.Connection (TLSSettings (..))
import Network.HTTP.Conduit

main :: IO ()
main = catch (do
                request <- parseRequest "https://github.com/"
                let settings = mkManagerSettings (TLSSettingsSimple True False False) Nothing
                manager <- newManager settings
                res <- httpLbs request manager
                print res)
             (\e -> case e of
                      HttpExceptionRequest{} -> putStrLn "Http request failed"
                      InvalidUrlException{} -> putStrLn "Bad URL")
```